# FileNotFoundException even though the file is present

Tags: java, xml, spring, filenotfoundexception, ioexception

I am trying to use a xml file in my Java project, I tried accessing the spring.xml file with a File
object to check if the code can find the file and can read it. The code is below:

```
    File f = null; 
    try{
        System.out.println("File found");
        f = new File("src/main/java/spring.xml");
        if (f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File exists");
            if (f.canRead()) {
                System.out.println("File is readable");
            } 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
```

This returns:

> File found

> File exists

> File is readable

But when I try the code below,

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(f.getAbsolutePath());
    Vehicle v1 = (Vehicle) context.getBean("vehicle");
    v1.drive();
```

It gives me a FileNotFoundException, on **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(f.getAbsolutePath())**.

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Work/Java/Enterprise/my-maven-project/src/main/java/spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Work/Java/Enterprise/my-maven-project/src/main/java/spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: Your code is attempting to load that file from the classpath. You are providing an absolute path to your file.

Comment: I tried the f.getPath() and giving the direct file name like, 

>new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml")

but nothing works.

Comment: It isn't a file it is a class path resource. Ditch the `src/main/resources` part (which is where it should be not in `src/main/java`. And just do `new ClassPathApplicationContext("spring.xml")`.

Comment: @f1sh got it. Used FileSystemXmlApplciationContext, now it works. Thanks

Comment: Don't use `FileSystemXmlApplication` in this case as it is part of the class path **not** the filesystem as soon as you package everything in a jar/war.

Comment: However that way of managing exceptions is very bad: always use `printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out`.

Comment: @M.Deinum got it. Moved the xml file to resource, now it works. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Pino I just wanted to see if the code can look up for the file or not, it won't be the part of the final code. Thanks for the suggestion btw.